# How to not accept additional fields in incoming JSON request body

Tags: java, json, spring, model-view-controller

I have a Spring Boot server that listens on endpoint. I accept `@RequestBody` as an object:

```
class Body {
   private String name;
}
```

I want it to accept requests like:

```
{
   "name": "some_name"
}
```

However, it also accepts:

```
{
   "name": "some_name",
   "dummy key":"dummy key value"
}
```

In that case I want it to throw error. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the controller when saving:

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public ResponseEntity<Body> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody Body saveUser) {
    Body createdUser = userService.save(saveUser);
    
    return new ResponseEntity<>(createdUser, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

When Spring finds an argument annotated with @Valid, it automatically validates the argument and throws an exception if the validation fails.

Or you can add this in the `application.properties`:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true
```

This helps us to make deserialization fail on unknown properties and throw an exception which we can handle using `handleHttpMessageNotReadable`.

Create controller advice to handle exceptions:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(
            HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
            HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity("Your Response Object", 
                HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I want to do It only in controller, using `@Valid` unfortunately does not work. When I add the change in config it works but everywhere so I have a lot of errors since I use ObjectMapper in other parts of the code.

Comment: that could be the solution. I don't know exactly how your code is so can't say for sure, but try maybe that can work.

Comment: unfortunately it works like your solution - so not exactly how I want it to

Comment: maybe you can ask another question with sharing your code, that might help you to get your solution the way you want.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR;

If you want the controller to return an error **when the `RequestBody` does not match what you are expecting** it is enough to add this to your `application.properties`:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true
```

This will return a default 400 response on malformed requests.

### The `@Valid` annotation

**Adding the `@Valid` annotation to your controller performs constraint validation** and it will only fail when, for example, you mark a field as to be of a maximum value of `1` but the request tries to set it to `2`. As per the docs:

> Marks a property, method parameter or method return type for validation cascading. Constraints defined on the object and its properties are validated when the property, method parameter or method return type is validated.

But **since you are not using any of the tools provided by `jakarta.validation` this annotation will have no effect on your code**.

Answer (score 0):

#### Configuring JSON request body deserialization rules in Spring

When configuring Spring's handling of unknown properties (fields) in JSON request body, the following are used in combination:

1. **Global level property (application.properties):**

   ```
   spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true/false
   ```
2. **Class level annotation (respective entity class):**

   ```java
   @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=false/true)
   ```

##### 1. Global property (`spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties`)

If set to `true`, any field(s) in the JSON payload that do not have a corresponding field in the Java entity class, will throw an exception.

For instance, a POST request to your endpoint with the following JSON body will result in client getting the response - 400 BAD REQUEST:

```
{
   "name": "some_name",
   "dummy key":"dummy key value"
}
```

If set to `false` (default behaviour), any extra fields are simply ignored.

##### 2. `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation (over entity class)

- `ignoreUnknown=false`: An exception will be thrown if there are any fields in the JSON payload that do not correspond to fields in the Java class.
- `ignoreUnknown=true`: Extra fields are simply ignored.

#### Problem (default case)

Logically you should be able to set the global property in `application.properties` and use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation to override this for classes you want to make an exception.

However, as of Spring 4.1, the default global property is set to `false` (was set to `true` in older versions) and it cannot be overridden with  `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)` at the class level.

This means that Spring will continue ignoring extra fields in JSON request body even if you annotate the class with
`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=false)` unless you configure the global default behaviour.

#### Solution

**Option 1:**

- Explicitly set `spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true` in `application.properties`.
- For entity classes where you don't want to enforce this behavior, annotate them with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)`.
- Remember that vice-versa doesn't work, which was the problem.

**Option 2:**

- In your `@Configuration` class, add the following bean:

  ```java
  @Bean
  public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder mapperBuilder() {
      return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().failOnUnknownProperties(true);
  }
  ```
- This brings back the old behavior, equivalent to setting `spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true`.
- And you can then simply override this in entity classes if necessary via `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)`.